# How to sort List<String> list numerically?

Tags: java, sorting

I have a `List<String> list` which is initialized to an arrayList. That is,

```
List<String>list = new ArrayList();
```

It has the following elements.

```
   [1,bread, 1,turkey, 10,potato, 11,plum, 12,carrot, 2,milk, 2,rice]
```

I would like to sort the list so that the numbers are in ascending order. For example,

`[1,bread,1 turkey,2,milk,2,rice,10,potato,11,plum,12,carrot]`

How can I do that?

Comment: If your input list has 5 string elements instead of 10, it's impossible to tell this from your post.  You're using commas both to separate the elements, and as characters that are part of the strings, and I can't tell what you're trying to do.  Please use quote marks next time.

Answer (score 2):

Java is an Object-Oriented language, and you should use it.

So, create a new class with two fields: `int` and `String`.

Now parse your strings and create objects, i.e. `1,bread` is parsed into the `int` value `1`, and the `String` value `bread`.

Next, make your class implement `Comparable`, and implement the `compareTo` method to order the objects by the `int` value.

Finally, now that `List<String>` was converted to `List<MyObj>`, call `Collections.sort(list)`.

Answer (score 2):

You're not trying to sort the elements in the `List`--you're trying to sort *pairs* of elements.  You can't do that with a simple `sort`.  What you'll need to do is:

1. Define a class with two fields, an `int` and a `String`.  Make the class implement `Comparable`.
2. Define a comparator for the class that compares the `int` fields to get the order you want.  You'll have to decide what your comparator will do if the `int` fields are equal (do you want the `String` fields to be in ascending order?)
3. Create a `List<YourClass>` whose size is half the size of the original list, by going through the source list in pairs, something like

   `for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i += 2) {`

   create a `YourClass` by converting `list.get(i)` to an `int`, and using `list.get(i+1)` as the `String` field

   `}`
4. Sort the new list
5. If desired, recreate a `List<String>` by going through the `List<YourClass>` and adding a `String` conversion of the `int`, followed by the `String` field from `YourClass`, to the new list.

I don't know what you're planning to do with the `String` list, but in most cases it will make your program easier if you create a `List<YourClass>` list as soon as possible, and work with `YourClass` objects throughout the rest of the program

Comment: Create minds [think alike](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40944414/5221149) ;-). Anyway, notice that there is no space after the comma separating the number and the string, so input is `{"1,bread", "1,turkey", ...}`, not `{"1", "bread", "1", "turkey", ...}`.

Comment: @Andreas Aack, if you're right, that's a really unclear way to post a question.  I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you could provide a custom `Comparator` which understands the structure of each individual `String` element and can parse and compare them properly. Something like this:

```
@Test
public void testShouldSortByNumber() {
    // Arrange
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1,bread", "1,turkey", "10,potato", "11,plum", "12,carrot", "2,milk", "2,rice");
    final List<String> EXPECTED_LIST = Arrays.asList("1,bread", "1,turkey", "2,milk", "2,rice", "10,potato", "11,plum", "12,carrot");

    // Act
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            try {
                int i1 = Integer.parseInt(o1.split(",")[0]);
                int i2 = Integer.parseInt(o2.split(",")[0]);
                // If the numbers are equal, could order by alpha on the second part of the string split
                return i1 < i2 ? -1 : i1 == i2 ? 0 : 1;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Lots of possible errors above -- NPE, NFE, invalid string format, etc.
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return 0;
        }
    });

    // Assert
    assert list.equals(EXPECTED_LIST);
}
```

The more complex answer is that you should better define your problem -- what should the result be if an element is empty or null, if the numbers are equal are the other strings compared lexicographically or is it irrelevant?

You may also want to use a different data structure -- if the content of each element is really two different logical concepts, a tuple or class may be correct. Or, you may want to use a `SortedMap` (of which `TreeMap` is probably the best implementation here) where the key is the "ingredient" and the value is the "count" (or "cost", I don't have any context on the numerical value).

You can also enhance the code above with a lambda if you have access to JDK 8+.